# Cluster points of the sequence $a_n(x):=nx-\lfloor nx \rfloor$

Tags: sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I have $a_n(x):=nx-\lfloor nx \rfloor$ where $x$ is real. I want to show that if $x$ is rational, then $a_n(x)$ has finitely many cluster points, if $x$ is irrational, then every real $a$ with $0\leq a \leq 1$ is cluster point of $a_n(x)$. I don't know where to start, through your help, I will understand cluster point, sequences more deeply. I am stuck how to show those 2 cases, i am still bad at proof-thinking.

Comment: You will find some useful information in [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202392/cluster-points-of-multiples-of-the-fractional-part-of-an-irrational-number).

Comment: Don't know where to start? Start by retrieving the relevant definitions ("cluster point", "rational" etc) and write down what they mean in the particular case of your $a_n(x)$.

Comment: okay thanks, Henning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: If $x$ is rational, we can write $x=m+\frac{a}n$ for some integers $m,a$, and $n$ such that $n>0$ and $0\le a<n$. (Why?) Clearly $m=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $a_1(x)=\frac{a}n$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
a_k(x)&=kx-\lfloor kx\rfloor\\
&=km+\frac{ka}n-\left\lfloor km+\frac{ka}n\right\rfloor\\
&=km+\frac{ka}n-\left(km+\left\lfloor\frac{ka}n\right\rfloor\right)\\
&=\frac{ka}n-\left\lfloor\frac{ka}n\right\rfloor\;.
\end{align*}$$

Use this to find a very simple relationship between $a_k(x)$ and $a_{k+n}(x)$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/189402/12042) to an earlier question covers the case of irrational $x$; it’s complete, but it’s pretty concise, so you may have to stare at it a bit to see just how it works.

Comment: Thanks Brian, great, i am studying your answer

Comment: @doniyor: You’re welcome; feel free to ping me if you get badly stuck.

Comment: i will, Brian. :). thank you so much for helping