# Prove that $(nx-\lfloor nx \rfloor)_{n\geq 1}$ has a finite number of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Prove that $(nx-\lfloor nx \rfloor)_{n\geq 1}$ has a finite number of limit points with $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x>0$. Furthermore $\lfloor .\rfloor:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$ the floor function

I observed [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267004/cluster-points-of-the-sequence-a-nx-nx-lfloor-nx-rfloor). I didn't really help me unfortunately. I am completely stumped when it comes to the proof. Could anyone of you give me a hint? Would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $x>0$.

Comment: The question's been updated

Comment: There are only finitely many different values in the sequence, so it cannot have any other limit points

Comment: Why are there only finitely many different values in the sequence?

Comment: It might help to write $x$ as $l+\frac{k}{m}$ where $0\le k < m$ and $k, l, m$ integers.

Comment: @Para, if $x=p/q$ then the only posible values are $0,1/q,2/q,\ldots,(q-1)/q$. (Not all of those are necessarily hit).

Comment: Hi Cameron, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Henning Makholm, doesn't this prove that there can not be an infinite number of limit points?